# Combine two SUMIFS statements?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

How do I combine the following two sumifs statement?

```
=SUMIFS($I$50:$I$69,$G$50:$G$69,"Non-*")+SUMIFS($I$50:$I$69,$G$50:$G$69,P16)
```

Comment: If the two criteria were string constants like `{"non-*", "abc"}` there would be no problem but you cannot combine cell values through a reference and a string constant in a string constant array.

Comment: While there are work-arounds involving more calculation intensive routines, you are probably using the best method already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are limiting the ranges already, SUMPRODUCT may look a bit better but it is not going to improve calculation load.

```
=SUMPRODUCT($I$50:$I$69, SIGN(($G$50:$G$69=P16)+(LEFT($G$50:$G$69, 4)="non-")))
```

Comment: is sumproduct slower than sumifs?

Comment: Yes. Even when avoiding full column references, SUMIFS is faster.